# UNAUTHENTICATED ERROR : Firebase function called from android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have just started working with callable functions on firebase.
I deployed a function that gives the response hello world.
It worked fine when I tested it locally.
Now I am trying to call it from android app.
According to this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), these callable functions automatically pass the authentication data and deserialise the data to get the user id in the function. When I run as suggested in the document above , I get an Unauthenticated error.
I have used google sign in using firebase auth in the app. I dont want to make it public and keep it private so only the users can send requests. Is there any way I could manually include authentication in the header of the request.
Here is the code from the call

```
               sendmessage(string)
                        .addOnCompleteListener {
                            if (!it.isSuccessful){
                                val e= it.exception
                                if(e is FirebaseFunctionsException){
                                    val code =e.code
                                    val details = e.details
                                    Log.d("Firebase error",code.toString()+details.toString())
                                }
                          
                            }
                            else{
                                Log.d("result obtained",it.result.toString())
                            }
                        }
```

```
private fun sendmessage(question:String): Task<String> {
        val data = hashMapOf(
            "question" to question,
            "push" to true
        )

        return functions
            .getHttpsCallable("detectIntent")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith {
                val result=it.result?.data as String
                result
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Callable functions don't provide any amount of control over what happens in the HTTP headers.  Authentication is handled automatically, based on the state of the user signed in through Firebase Auth.  If you're not getting an authenticated user in your function in `context.auth`, that means you made the request before sign-in was complete.

Comment: But I can see the user has signed up under the users tab in the authentication panel of the firebase console. Do I need to add some invoke permissions for the function in the google cloud console

Comment: No, there's nothing extra you have to do.

Comment: The user needs to be signed in at the time of the request. There's nothing you're showing here that prove this to be true. Having an account isn't enough - the user needs to be actively signed into the app.

Comment: I checked if the user is signed in through GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAcocunt(context) and it showed the user is signed in and even after that the call to functions is giving the same error

Comment: The only thing that matters is if Firebase Auth sees the user signed in, not the provider SDK.

Comment: Is this related to Google Cloud Functions? Is there something not working with this?